# Does using sequelize ORM prevent sql injection

Tags: node.js, security, orm, sequelize.js

I'm new to backend so I would like to make sure the data saved to the database is safe. I already got an answer, but I would still like a second opinion.

What the app does...

A user inputs some text into an input field and the app checks if there are any "typos" / misuse of the word and informs the user how to correct the errors.

The text user inputs is saved to the database along with uuid for tracking changes made to the text during that session.

The app currently has no other interaction with database.

I might have gone overboard, trying to use `Sequelize.Op.eq`, but it returned that an error shown below.

Current working example:

```
const UserText = sequelize.define('userText', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    uuidv4: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    },
    userText_field: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    }
});

async function addStringToTable(uuid, string ) {
    try{
        await UserText.create({
            uuidv4: uuid ,
            userText_field: string 
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

This code throws an error (is `Sequelize.Op.eq` needed?)

```
async function addStringToTable(uuid, string ) {
    // Save the input string to the database
    try{
        await UserText.create({
            uuidv4: { [Sequelize.Op.eq]: uuid },
            userText_field: { [Sequelize.Op.eq]: string }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

```
//error:
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'uuidv4 cannot be an array or an object',
      type: 'string violation',
      path: 'uuidv4',
      value: [Object],
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [userText],
      validatorKey: 'not_a_string',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'userText_field cannot be an array or an object',
      type: 'string violation',
      path: 'userText_field',
      value: [Object],
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [userText],
      validatorKey: 'not_a_string',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    }
```

Follow up question is, since I have no other interaction with the database, is using ORM enough or should some other security measures be taken? Since there is no "admin" panel, no users, and in general no access to the database from the front end, is the database safe from tempering / unauthorised lookup? Is there anything else I should look into / take care of.

I know the followup question are too broad, but any advice would be welcome.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding of `Sequelize.Op.eq`.  This is "equal" operator. https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#operators

It will generate a query `= value` which is used in `WHERE` clause.  `create` which generates `INSERT` query won't have `WHERE` clause.   What are you hoping the function would do or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks. I op.eq is operator equal (I assume). I just want to make sure that the data saved into the database doesn't mess anything up. (So I went overboard and tried `Sequalize.op.eq`). I was assuming that `Sequalize.op.eq` would check if the data is a string/text type.

Comment: `eq` is not for checking.  It is generating the equal SQL. I think you are looking for constraints and validations. https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/validations-and-constraints/

there are some data types checks but I don't think you have string type check.  If you pass array, the code will crash.

Comment: thank you. Will check it out. Do you have any suggestion on how to further protect the database and app? Also write is as an answer and I'll accept